# Don't change the color of table row once visited

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my application to run in the same way as `gmail`  does. Once we visit the mail its color changes permanently even when we reload the page it remains the same

'Here is my fiddle'

http://jsfiddle.net/kZSjR/#&togetherjs=OpoxyFna4o

when i click on the 'po' button row color must change permanently like in gmail 
Thank you for your help

Comment: Why not use an anchor tag instead, then set style using pseudo class `:visited`

Comment: You need a database, unless you don't care if the user goes to the page from a different computer. Or a different browser. Or clears their cookies, or their cache...

Comment: From where are you getting your data... each mail piece has a "read/unread" attribute that the browser interprets.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage), like this:

```
$("#po").click(function(){
    localStorage.setItem("visited", true);
    $("#po").css("color", "black"); // visited
});
```

Now on page load,

```
$(window).load(function(){

    if(localStorage.getItem("visited"))
    {
        $("#po").css("color", "black"); // visited
    }
    else
    {
        $("#po").css("color", "green"); // not visited
    }

});
```

Alternatively, you can use cookies too (but their usage is becomes a bit lengthy IMO).

P.S. Note that localStorage can easily be modified by users, and is not to be used for storing sensitive user data. [Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108651/deleting-localstorage-data).

Comment: Thank you but its not working the row background color is not changing

Comment: @bindibhatt I made a small change in the first code. Please have a look. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: thank you it works and what of i want whole ror back-ground color visited?

Comment: If you want to change the `background-color`, use `$("#po").css("background-color", "color_here")`.

Comment: can i use class instead of id? because only first row gets affected

Comment: Sure, use `$(".className")` <-- See the dot (`.`) there in place of hash (`#`).

Comment: by default it takes `green` value `:after` as well as `:before` click

Comment: You can change it. I have set green in the `else` block, modify the color name as you like.

Comment: i know but it is `not visited` color but `after` visit also it shows ` green` color

Comment: no change cannot show any color..can you help me from team viwer?

Comment: I can assure you it works. [See here](http://jsbin.com/wumolige/1/edit). Go and click on 12345. Run with JS. Reload the page. Run with JS. And see 12345 turns black.

Comment: what if a have more then one row with same class ? and color change should be only on visited button